# boot time increase after upgrading ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

Boot time is increased after the upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04. I do not have any issue regarding nvidia driver (nvidia driver re-installed after the upgrade) and works perfect. I am using vmware and I had also re-build it after the upgrade. It is also working fine. I do not how to increase boot time. I am sure that if I perform clean installation of 14.04 it will be quicker boot time. Could you please suggest me how to decrease system boot time?
Defrag disk etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux there is no defrag, by the way I suggest you to make a document backup and then a clean install of 14.04...this will be the best solution. Or you can try to clean the unnecessary files, tmp etc. with bleachbit.

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit 
sudo bleachbit
```

Use carefully.